# Access denied for user who has full access to some files in their own folder

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory, network-share

I have a very similar case as this user:  [Access denied on some files on Win2008R2 DC share](https://serverfault.com/questions/301494/access-denied-on-some-files-on-win2008r2-dc-share)

This is on a windows 2008 R2.  The user has Win7 pro.

The user has their own home folder on the server.  Every file, except one, the user can read/write/modify at their own will.  No problems - except this one file.  She gets "access denied"  I can open it (as domain admin).  Another user can open it (because she's in the domain admin group).

I did run the AccessEnum tool and the read/write permissions are all identical for all files.  So, I can't explain why the user can't open this one single file.  Out of all her files in sub-folders and such.  No problems.  This one file is causing a headache.

What do you think could be wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm suspecting that you're using CREATOR OWNER on the parent object. Check if the user has NTFS ownership on the file. If not - change the ownership and reset permissions on the parent object to make inheritance kick in.

Comment: I (domain admin) was the owner.  I set the user as the owner and re-applied her permissions (full access to her own documents) and that did the trick.  No more issues w/her spreadsheeet.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What type of file is it? I've seen access denied failures for some files (access/excel/etc) that call data to a file in another location, so that the failure is in fact on the second call out to data in another location, and not in the actual file that is being opened.

Comment: It is an excel file (xlsx).  I'll have to open it locally on the server and see if it's making any calls or references to another spreadsheet - but I can't imagine it's doing that.  It's just a small spreadsheet with some May 2014 payroll information in it.